# How do the dimensions of an "infinite" bar of chocolate change?

Tags: geometry

Here is a GIF image illustrating a supposedly "infinite" supply of white chocolate.

[image]

After watching this repeatedly, I can't definitively say why it doesn't add up. It clearly can't be infinite and the sizes of the pieces don't seem to be changed/edited. My guess is that the volume of the spaces between pieces somehow adds up to the final piece's volume.

However, the real question I have is: **how have the dimensions of the array of chocolate changed**? That is, if you start with a $6\times 4$ grid of chocolate pips, what are the final dimensions of the *almost* complete grid? I figure that height need not be considered because the cuts are made normal to the table surface.

Comment: generally, if you carefully draw (including finding the slopes of all relevant line segments) you find that the after picture has a slim empty part, probably triangular here

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_square_puzzle

Comment: What makes it an infinite bar of chocolate?

Comment: @RossMillikan Presumably, the OP meant *inexhaustible* (in supply) and not *infinite* (in span).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well here's a picture:

[image]

Basically, the pieces that were moved end up being 1/4 shorter than they should be.

Comment: This would be better if you highlighted the "grid" formed by the chocolate pieces.

Comment: @columbus8myhw Alright.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The ending result is actually 1/5 of a piece shorter than the original bar. That amount(1/5) times 5 pieces across is equal to the extra piece

Comment: This is not the same one as the OP's

Comment: This variation is very interesting. It is nice to see that the extra piece's area is easily verified. But what about the $6\times4$ case above? That one interests me more because the "perforated" lines seem to match up better all around.